# Ant: javac cannot find class even though it's in the classpath

Tags: java, ant, classpath

Our build.xml file contains the following:

```
<path id="our.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${in.libs}"/>
    <fileset file="/home/ouruser/fortify/Core/lib/sourceanalyzer.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <pathconvert property="test" refid="our.classpath"/>
    <echo message="CLASSPATH=${test}"/>

    <javac debug="true"
           debuglevel="source,lines,vars"
           destdir="${out.classes}"
           includeAntRuntime="no"
           fork="false"
           source="1.7" target="1.7">
        <src path="${src1.dir}"/>
        <src path="${src2.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="our.classpath"/>
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:-path"/>
        <compilerarg line="-proc:none"/>
        <compilerarg line="-s &quot;${out.classes}&quot;"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="fortify">
     <antcall target="compile">
         <param name="build.compiler" value="com.fortify.dev.ant.SCACompiler"/>
     </antcall>
</target>
```

When I run `ant fortify`, I get the following output:

```
fortify:

compile:
 [echo] CLASSPATH=<a long list of jar files snipped>:/home/ouruser/fortify/Core/lib/sourceanalyzer.jar

BUILD FAILED
/home/ouruser/build.xml:542: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ouruser/build.xml:230: Class not found: com.fortify.dev.ant.SCACompiler
```

As you can see from the `echo` output, the sourceanalyzer.jar file is in the classpath that is used by the `javac` task.

When I run `jar -tvf /home/ouruser/fortify/Core/lib/sourceanalyzer.jar | grep SCACompiler.class`, the SCACompiler class is listed:

```
8408 Fri Apr 04 11:17:26 EDT 2014 com/fortify/dev/ant/SCACompiler.class
```

So why does Ant say `Class not found: com.fortify.dev.ant.SCACompiler`?

Comment: I too facing same issue. Any solution?

Comment: @KiranNunna Try running `ant -lib path/to/sourceanalyzer.jar fortify`

Comment: I don't mean to bring up a dead post, but I have this issue as well. -lib is set

Answer (score 0):

In place of `com/fortify/dev/ant/SCACompiler.class` class, use

```
com.fortify.dev.ant.SourceanalyzerTask
```